# using LDA for dimension reduction / clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, text-mining, lda

I'm currently facing a text mining problem where my goal is to identify clusters within a corpus of short texts. 
The idea is, that these clusters represent some kind of technical/domain specific content which all members of the respective cluster have in common. 
The final evaluation of the clustering has to be made from a domain knowledge based perspetive.

I worked myself through a bunch of different approaches. 
Topic modeling with lda seems a good one to start with. 
So each of my documents is represented through a mixture of different topics (which are based on the coherent occrurance of single words or n_grams)

My first idea was to use the resulting topics as clusters/groups to group my documents. 
But one single document can consist of different topics, so I'm not sure wether this is a good idea. 
Furthermore, as LDA is not using a distance measure to calculate it's topics, I'm lacking some kind of metric to evalute my lda based clusters. Because of the fact, that I'm missing a given ground truth I'm bound to methods, which are not bound to a given ground truth. I used the silhouette score to evalute my clusters, but while this metric is based on distances,  lda is not. I'm not sure wether it actualy makes sense.

My second thought was to use the lda results as a preprocessing step for dimension reduction. 
On these new Input vector I could apply distance based clustering methods like agglomerative clustering, kmeans, dbscan.

I also found some posts and papers, which pointed to self organizing maps to solve that kind of problem. Is this approach worth following it, compared to the methods described above?

Is it a reasonable approach to use lda topics as clusters or as a preprocessing step?
What are metrics to evalute non distance approaches like lda?
Are there any other approaches which I should take into account?

Comment: define "short text" in terms of number of words.

Comment: Silhouette etc. are just heuristics. Rather look at you data, than a single "evaluation" number.

Comment: The documents contain between ~ 100 and 1500 characters.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse : I know that my final evaluation should be based on a domain specific point of view but withou any previous (heuristic) Evaluation, I don't know wether there are 5, 20 or 500 hidden Clusters.

Comment: In my experience, the heuristics won't really tell you either.